# Accessing DynamoDB through Lambda with Python without hitting read/write capacity

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, slack-api

For some reason, every time I run my Lambda function I get an error from DynamoDB:

```
INSUFFICIENT_DATA     Assets-ReadCapacityUnitsLimit-BasicAlarm
ConsumedReadCapacityUnits >= 240 for 5 datapoints within 5 minutes
```

I am new to everything AWS and Python, so hopefully, someone can just glance at this code and point out where I'm being dumb.

What I am trying to do is use the '!Addme' command from slack to add users to a database. I already managed to get slack and lambda to talk to each other in the form of sending a command and receiving an answer. For my next step, I wanted to learn how to make Lambda pull data from dynamoDB.

From my alarm, it looks like I am making too many read/write requests a second. This could just be my lack of python understanding. So my question is, on my defined functions (getAssetTableIDList() and getUserIDExistance(userID)) am I doing something stupid?

I appreciate any and all help. Thanks.

Basic info on my DynamoDB:
Key = userID (string)
Read/Write capacity = 1

```
################################
# Slack Lambda handler.
################################

import boto3
import os
import logging
import urllib

# Grab data from the environment.
BOT_TOKEN   = os.environ["BOT_TOKEN"]
ASSET_TABLE = os.environ["ASSET_TABLE"]
REGION_NAME = os.getenv('REGION_NAME', 'us-east-1')

dynamo = boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name=REGION_NAME, endpoint_url="http://localhost:8000")

# Define the URL of the targeted Slack API resource.
SLACK_URL = "https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage"

def getAssetTableIDList():
    tables = dynamo.scan(TableName=ASSET_TABLE)

    userIDList = {}
    for item in tables['Items']:
        userList[item['userID']['S']]

    return userIDList 

def getUserIDExistance(userID):
    userIDList = getAssetTableIDList()

    if userID in userIDList:
        userIDExist = true

    return userIDExist 

def lambda_handler(data, context):
    # Slack challenge answer.
    if "challenge" in data:
        return data["challenge"]

    # Grab the Slack channel data.
    slack_event  = data['event']
    slack_user   = slack_event["user"]
    slack_text   = slack_event["text"]
    channel_id   = slack_event["channel"]
    slack_userID = slack_user["ID"]
    slack_reply  = ""

    # Ignore bot messages.
    if "bot_id" in slack_event:
        logging.warn("Ignore bot event")
    else:

        # Start data sift.
        if slack_text.startswith("!networth"):
            slack_reply = "Your networth is: "
        elif slack_text.startwith("!price"):
            command,asset = text.split()
            slack_reply = "The price of a(n) %s is: " % (asset)
        elif slack_text.startwith("!Addme"):
            if not getUserIDExistance(slack_userID):
                slack_reply = "Added user: %s" % (slack_user)
                dynamo.update_item(TableName=ASSET_TABLE, 
                    Key={'userID':{'S':'slack_userID'},
                    AttributeUpdates= {
                        'resources':{
                            'Action': 'ADD',
                            'Value': {'N': '1000'}
                        }
                    }
                )
            else
                slack_reply = "User %s(%s) already exists" % (slack_user, slack_userID)

        # We need to send back three pieces of information:
        data = urllib.parse.urlencode(
            (
                ("token", BOT_TOKEN),
                ("channel", channel_id),
                ("text", slack_reply)
            )
        )
        data = data.encode("ascii")

        # Construct the HTTP request that will be sent to the Slack API.
        request = urllib.request.Request(
            SLACK_URL, 
            data=data, 
            method="POST"
        )
        # Add a header mentioning that the text is URL-encoded.
        request.add_header(
            "Content-Type", 
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        )

        # Fire off the request!
        urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()

    # Everything went fine.
    return "200 OK"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing a full table scan to load the entire table into memory, then iterating through every object in the table in order to see if an entry exists. Instead of doing a scan you need to do a query, with the ID in question, and let DynamoDB tell you if the item exists or not.

Comment: So where I have two functions (load table and check user), I can potentially do this in one line? I will look into the query instead of scan. Thank you. :D

Comment: Well you need to get rid of the load table function all together. The check user function should run a query against the DynamoDB table.

Comment: `def getAssetExistance(asset, element, table):
    dynamoTable = dynamo.Table(table)
    response = dynamoTable.query(KeyConditionExpression=Key(element).eq(asset)
        
    return bool(response)` Think this is what you were talking about. Am I barking up the right tree now?